# List could not be found at site in autohosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, mvc

I have a sharepoint autohosted app integrated with mvc model (`DocumentsMvc` project)

I created a list (`AwaitingDocuments`) by adding it to sharepoint project (`Documents`) and created a simple view in which I want to display some basic information from the list.

However when I try to debug the app it catches exception stating that:

> List 'AwaitingDocuments' does not exist at site with URL https://someserver.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite

I tried to access the list directly through https://someserver.sharepoint.com/sites/somesite/someapp/lists/AwaitingDocuments and it was there.

Here is a look at my solution setup:

[image: solution]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Double check that the list is added to your feature!

Comment: Yes, it's added. Under "Items in the Feature" :`AwaitingDocuments` List Instance and `Documents` Module.

Comment: I had the same problem, how to get the list ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any list you deploy as part of you App will be added to the AppWeb (yes such a web is created when you add SharePoint items to your App, even though the App is Autohosted) not to the HostWeb

Comment: Ok it works now, I changed access method to `web` from `SPContext.Web` to `SPContext.Site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Site.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Documents")`. Thanks for directing me to the right issue.

Comment: Well spotted per +1

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming that your app doesn't have the proper "read" permissions to see this list.

Add the read permission to the AppManifest for the list service. This should then work.

Comment: Thanks for reply but that wasn't the problem in my case. I had the required permissions turned on.